# How to simplify this JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regex that results matches ether an optional (number or specific code) and optional '-' and another optional (number or specific code) not NOT null.

This is the regex that I have and it works, but I would like to simplify it:

```
/((\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)|((\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)-)|((\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)-(\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl))|(-)|(-(\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)))/

/* these should all work */
"34-56"
"-56"
"34"
"34-"
"-"
"xs-md"
"-lg"
"sm"
"md-"

/* these should not work */
"test"
"500px"
"16-max"
""
```

test regex:
https://regex101.com/r/Uz2fGE/2

Comment: `((\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)|((\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)-)` is `((\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)-?)`

Comment: Do you really need all those capturing groups?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I don't know. I know that it works like this, but every time I try to simplify it it stops working.

Comment: Capturing groups are for using the captured substrings in the output later. Do you need that? (If not, you should use non-capturing groups instead)

Comment: @MakPo If you don't know whether the capturing groups are necessary, that's something you'll need to find out. The code might be specifically designed for that regex, which would mean any attempt to simplify the regex will break the code unless you also change the code that interprets the matches.

Comment: I'm the one designing the regex. The code needs to test that the string returns `true` for all of the top test cases and false for all of the bottom test cases. I could just run with what I have and move on, but I just want to get better at regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to this!

```
((\d*|xs|sm|md|lg|xl|-){1}-?(\d*|xs|sm|md|lg|xl))?
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/%EC%A0%95%EA%B7%9C%EC%8B%9D

```
*: >= 0
?: 0 or 1
(): pattern
\d: number
|: or
```

Comment: yours allows for empty strings. I need it to not allow empty strings.

Comment: To disallow empty strings, you can put `(?!$)` at the beginning of the regex, but this will only work if the match must consist of the entire string.

Comment: @4castle This is enough.

Comment: @seunggabi Your updated regex matches `--`, but the original regex doesn't. That's the only flaw the OP might care about.

Comment: That works. Putting the `-` inside the first grouping was smart. Thank you.

Comment: @4castle your point is good. but, the variables pattern given as input are limited. It is safe because it does not appear. such as `333-333`

Comment: This is what I ultimately ended up using:`/^(\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl|-)-?(\d+|xs|sm|md|lg|xl)?$/`